# Promises, pass additional parameters to then chain

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

A promise, just for example:

```
var P = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  var a = 5;
  if (a) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve(a);
    }, 3000);
  } else {
    reject(a);
  }
});
```

After we call the `.then()` method on the promise:

```
P.then(doWork('text'));
```

Then `doWork` function looks like this:

```
function doWork(data) {
  return function(text) {
    // sample function to console log
    consoleToLog(data);
    consoleToLog(b);
  }
}
```

How can I avoid returning an inner function in doWork, to get access to data from the promise and text parameters? Are there any tricks to avoiding the inner function?

Comment: Why would anyone intentionally renounce **currying**? In order to use the hideous `bind` method? - which is also extremely slow.

Comment: @ftor I don't understand you, can you please provide some code for clarification?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to create a new function with a value passed to its first argument, like this

```
P.then(doWork.bind(null, 'text'))
```

and you can change `doWork` to,

```
function doWork(text, data) {
  consoleToLog(data);
}
```

Now, `text` will be actually `'text'` in `doWork` and `data` will be the value resolved by the Promise.

**Note:** Please make sure that you attach a rejection handler to your promise chain.

---

**Working program:** [Live copy on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20doWork(text%2C%20data)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(text%20%2B%20data%20%2B%20text)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20Promise(function%20(resolve%2C%20reject)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20a%20%3D%205%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(a)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(a)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%203000)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(a)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20.then(doWork.bind(null%2C%20'text'))%0A%20%20.catch(console.error)%3B)

```
function doWork(text, data) {
  console.log(text + data + text);
}

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var a = 5;
    if (a) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        resolve(a);
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      reject(a);
    }
  })
  .then(doWork.bind(null, 'text'))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: thanks, that helps, earlier i try doWork.call(this, 'text'), but data was replaced by 'text'

Comment: `call` invokes a function in-place, `bind` creates a new function, however both accept an execution context as their first argument.

Answer (score 125):

Perhaps the most straightforward answer is:

```
P.then(function(data) { return doWork('text', data); });
```

Or, since this is tagged `ecmascript-6`, using arrow functions:

```
P.then(data => doWork('text', data));
```

I find this most readable, and not too much to write.

Comment: In your es6 example & 'classes' how would I go about replacing "text" with a reference to an item in an array I was iterating through when creating the promise. EG: `fetch(request).then(data => this.AssetRetrieved(jData.parms[i].Value, data));`

Comment: @Reahreic That sounds like a variation of the JS closures in a loop problem. Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16661498/918910) helpful? If not, please consider asking a new question with more details.

Answer (score 5):

Use currying.

```
var P = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var a = 5;
    if (a) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(a);
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        reject(a);
    }
});

var curriedDoWork = function(text) {
    return function(data) {
        console.log(data + text);
    }
};

P.then(curriedDoWork('text'))
.catch(
    //some error handling
);
```

Comment: b careful with this, if you create `curriedDoWork` into a promise by doing `return new Promise()` on the first line of this function, the promise is executed as soon as you call `curriedDoWork()` (like you do in `..then(curriedDoWork('text'))`

Comment: @Flame: short answer, for your convenience you can wrap the promise into a function, if you like to do so.

Comment: @yks, you could have indicated this syntax which is quite interesting  const curriedWork = text => data =>  console.log(data + text)

Comment: @germain ah yes i have seen this form before, gotta love functional programming. However i experience arrow functions break in some browser, so i tend to avoid it now.

Comment: @yks, only Internet Explorer doesn't support it and will never, because of Edge, Internet Explorer last build was December 9th 2015. Let's move on ~

Answer (score 3):

The new answer to this question is to use arrow functions *(which automatically bind the `this` and are much more readable)*. Google for links such as:
https://2ality.com/2016/02/arrow-functions-vs-bind.html

You can set the text like:

```
this.text = 'text';
P.then(data => doWork(data));
```

Note: `this.text` inside `doWork` will evaluate to 'text'.

This is suggested by jib above and that (or this!) should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash offers a nice alternative for this exact thing.

```
 P.then(_.bind(doWork, 'myArgString', _));

 //Say the promise was fulfilled with the string 'promiseResults'

 function doWork(text, data) {
     console.log(text + " foo " + data);
     //myArgString foo promiseResults
 }
```

Or, if you'd like your success function to have only one parameter (the fulfilled promise results), you can utilize it this way:

```
P.then(_.bind(doWork, {text: 'myArgString'}));

function doWork(data) {
    console.log(data + " foo " + this.text);
    //promiseResults foo myArgString
}
```

This will attach `text: 'myArgString'` to the `this` context within the function.

Answer (score 0):

use this so you can access global variable inside the promise body

```
var ref=this;
```

Example

```
p.then((data)=>{
  var ref=this;
});
```