# Programmatically add arguments to a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I need to create a function that receives a Promise as a first parameter and an array of its parameters (if it has at least one) or null if none.

My function looks this way:

```
var executeMappingStep = (promiseStatus, myPromise, myPromiseParams) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //if the execution was success, there's no need to invoke myPromise again
        if(promiseStatus.success == true)
           return resolve(promiseStatus.previousResponseSaved);

        if (myPromiseParams!= null) {
            //how I resolve this logic is my doubt
            myPromise.addArrayOfParameters(myPromiseParams);
        }

        myPromise().then(result => resolve(result)).catch(err => reject(err));
    });
};
```

I was reading about the **.bind()** function which works for functions but not for promises according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912459/promises-pass-additional-parameters-to-then-chain). I also saw something about the **.apply()** function, but this doesn't seems to be what I need.

### Edit

My function is invoked like *myFirstPromise* when there aren't parameters, and like *mySecondPromise* when I have at least one:

```
var executePromises = (myFirstPromise, mySecondPromisePromise) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //retrieve an array of every promise status
        var promisesStatus = getPromisesStatus();

        executeMappingStep(promisesStatus[0], myFirstPromise, null).then(result => {
                return convertToXml(result);
        }).then(result => {

            var parameters = {
                value1 : result,
                value2: [1,2,3],
                value3: "some string",
                value4: 10
            };  

            return executeMappingStep(promisesStatus[1], mySecondPromisePromise, parameters);
        }).then(result => resolve(result)).catch(err => reject(err));
    });
};

var myFirstPromise = function() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
        //some logic for first promise
    });
}

var mySecondPromise = function(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam, fourthParam) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
        //some logic for second promise with its params
    });
}
```

Probably, in the function **addArrayOfParameters** I need to loop into every property on the object (I realized that an array would not work), like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Is there a way to programmatically add parameters from an array before its resolved?

### Edit 2

The reason behind this logic is much complex, but this is pretty much what I need to solve. Basically, in my code, every promise can be executed with errors and there's a logic involved in the **executePromises** function which returns the status of every promise whether was successfully executed or not. This logic involves more than 10 promises chained, and if some of them fail e.g: promise number 5, then 6,7 etc, will have to be invoked again in some admin backend.

I don't what to replicate the logic for each promise, so that's why I wanted to create the **executeMappingStep** function to encapsulate that logic. 
Probably is hard to explain, I tried to simplify the most as I could. I made a few more changes to explain what I just said.

Comment: What parameters and how are they used by promise?

Comment: all of them are simple values, such as ints, strings or in the worst of the cases, an array of primitive types.

Comment: `myPromise().then(` looks like `myPromise` is a function that constructs a promise, not a promise... is there where you want to pass the params e.g. `myPromise(myPromiseParams).then(...`? your question is very confusing

Comment: Not clear what parameters you mean and how they are used.

Comment: How the paramaters in myPromiseParams should change the resolve value 'result' ? Give some examples

Comment: Allright, I will edit the question. Give a sec.

Comment: I think you should use async.waterfall

Comment: seems like an XY Problem.   Please explain what the code is actually supposed to achieve.

Comment: I apologize. I tried to simplify the problem but I couldn't. I added more details to the code and a description.

Comment: @MauroBilotti Let me know whether it may resolve your issue or not?

Comment: @Dipakchavda, I think that the problem with the async.waterfall is that I have to use values coming on the response of the previous one. I mean, mySecondPromise needs the response of myFirstPromise, am I clear?

Comment: @MauroBilotti so first promise output is input of second promise right?

Comment: @MauroBilotti Please review my updated answer it definitely may help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, I have complicated things a lot here, but anyway, this is the solution that I wanted.
It's good to know that the **.then** function can invoked in other place and the promises can be created with the needed arguments and then sent as parameter.

With that said:

```
var executePromises = (myFirstPromise, mySecondPromisePromise) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //retrieve an array of every promise status
        var promisesStatus = getPromisesStatus();

        executeMappingStep(promisesStatus[0], myFirstPromise()).then(result => {
                return convertToXml(result);
        }).then(result => {

            var mySecondPromisePromiseParameter = mySecondPromise(result, [1,2,3], "some string", 10);   

            return executeMappingStep(promisesStatus[1], mySecondPromisePromiseParameter);
        }).then(result => resolve(result)).catch(err => reject(err));
    });
};
```

An then, the **executeMappingStep** just receives the promise and invokes the *.then* internally, this way:

```
var executeMappingStep = (promiseStatus, myPromise) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //if the execution was success, there's no need to invoke myPromise again
        if(promiseStatus.success == true)
           return resolve(promiseStatus.previousResponseSaved);    

        myPromise.then(result => resolve(result)).catch(err => reject(err));
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably use async library may resolve your issue. Try to run code on your console and look into that.

With async library:

```
var async = require("async");
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        var methodParam = [1, 2, 3];
        console.log("first method called");
        callback(null, methodParam);
    },
    function (methodParams, callback) {
        var newParams = [4, 5, 6];
        newParams = methodParams.concat(newParams);
        console.log("second method called", methodParams);
        callback(null, newParams);
    }
], function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error occured");
    } else {
        console.log("final result", res);
    }
});
```

With promise:

```
var promise1 = (() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var methodParam = [1, 2, 3];
        console.log("first promise called");
        resolve(methodParam);
    });
});

var promise2 = ((methodParams) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var newParams = [4, 5, 6];
        newParams = methodParams.concat(newParams);
        console.log("second promise called", methodParams);
        resolve(newParams);
    });
});

promise1()
    .then((resPromise1) => {
        return promise2(resPromise1);
    }).then((resPromise2) => {
        console.log("final result", resPromise2);
    });
```

Comment: This does not seems to resolve the problem that I have. In every promise I need to use responses from the previous calls as in request. This means that in "then" function of the firstPromise, I need to invoke the second one. PD: I didn't downvote.